# Using Google Analytics On Subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I've created three websites on one root domain and two subdomains. In Google Analytics I've created three properties and each website has a different Google code snippet.

Do I need to make any configuration changes to the Google Analytics properties for this to work properly?

Thanks
Mike

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suited for [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 0):

Tracking will work normally and is independent as if they were different sites. Each property will track its own subdomain.

Everything then depends on what you want to achieve. In this case, by default, you will not have information about moving from one subdomain to another (the traffic will be Direct).